# volume name is too short elasticbeanstalk error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a dockerized app to elastic beanstalk. After I uploaded my zip file that contains my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, the console returns a

```
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z }'
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z + local 'CONTAINER_STOPPED_REASONS=web: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z 
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z db: '
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z + '[' -n 'Essential container in task exited' ']'
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z + error 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (web: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z 
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z db: )'
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z + echo 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (web: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z 
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z db: )'
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (web: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z 
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z db: )
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z + eventHelper.py --msg 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (web: CannotCreateContainerError: API error (400): create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z 
2018-05-09T20:08:15Z db: )' --severity ERROR
```

I looked into my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file but there are no volume name that is smaller than 2 characters, I updated all the `.` characters in the files to either `this` or `Code`, I have seen posts saying that there might be a path solving issue for windows but I am not sure how I can fix it.

I provided my `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerrun.aws.json` file for reference.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=name
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=db1
    ports:

      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    image: rdeng/test:latest
    build: this
    environment:
      - RDS_DB_NAME=db1
      - RDS_USERNAME=name
      - RDS_HOSTNAME=db
      - RDS_PASSWORD=password
      - RDS_PORT=5432
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py makemigrations && python /code/manage.py migrate && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - this:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                    "value": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "password"
                },
                {
                    "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
                    "value": "db1"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres:10.1",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
                    "sourceVolume": "Postgres_Data"
                }
            ],
            "name": "db",
            "memory":64,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5432,
                    "hostPort": 5432
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "bash",
                "-c",
                "python /code/manage.py makemigrations && python /code/manage.py migrate && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "RDS_DB_NAME",
                    "value": "db1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "RDS_USERNAME",
                    "value": "name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "RDS_HOSTNAME",
                    "value": "db"
                },
                {
                    "name": "RDS_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "password"
                },
                {
                    "name": "RDS_PORT",
                    "value": "5432"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "memory":64,
            "image": "dockerhubstuff/test:latest",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/code",
                    "sourceVolume": "code"
                }
            ],
            "name": "web",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
            },
            "name": "Postgres_Data"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "."
            },
            "name": "code"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also added a `.env` file within my directory that contains the `docker-compose.yml` file that contains this line

`COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

But the same error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be relevant anymore to @reddd__1, but perhaps it may be to other folks experiencing a similar issue.

As the error points out, the ECS task definition seems to be looking for a volume with name `.` as part of the list of volumes passed through the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file:

```
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
            },
            "name": "Postgres_Data"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "."
            },
            "name": "code"
        }
```

Perhaps the issue seems to be with the `sourcePath` value given to the `code` volume, as it points to a file or directory where the bind mount host volume is located (see "Volumes" section of the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)).

To fix this, try declaring the volume in the `docker-compose.yml` file and referencing it on the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, for instance:

In `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  this
```

Then in `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
            },
            "name": "Postgres_Data"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "this"
            },
            "name": "code"
        }
```

This should be able to register the ECS task definition with a properly named volume that is correctly defined in the `docker-compose` configuration.